# Change Camera Distance of Cinemachine in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my (2D) game, I am making a function that zooms out the camera, and I'm using cinemachine. Is there a way to do it in the script? I looked at the documentation and everywhere but didn't find anything. Only how to change the field of view (that can't work for me).

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKUFQ.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is creating a new virtual camera with your desired distance and position and disabling its GameObject to begin. Then, from a script, you can change the current camera to the new camera by disabling the current camera and enabling the new camera. Cinemachine will automatically handle the transition to the new camera.

Here is a method I use to manage multiple cameras in this way.

```
public GameObject[] Cameras;

public void ActivateCamera(int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Cameras.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == index)
        {
            Cameras[i].SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Cameras[i].SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @EnricoCortinovis that is strange, I am able to get a smooth transition on my end.

Comment: Sorry, Don't know why it wasn't working. Thanks for your answer! It is perfect :)

Comment: Also, why do you use GameObject instead of CinemachineVirtualCamera?

Comment: From our perspective, we do not need to worry about the implementation of the cameras. Cinemachine handles most of everything behind the scenes. We enable and disable the GameObjects as a way of exposing and hiding the camera we want to use. What this does is add or remove the objects from the scene (in our case, they happen to be cameras).

Answer (score 8):

After stumbling on a similar issue you had, i found out you can do this :

```
CinemachineComponentBase componentBase = virtualCamera.GetCinemachineComponent(CinemachineCore.Stage.Body);
if (componentBase is CinemachineFramingTransposer)
{
    (componentBase as CinemachineFramingTransposer).m_CameraDistance = 30; // your value
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception? 
1. I just provided this as guidance. virtualCamera variable needs to be a valid instance of CinemachineVirtualCamera.
2. What version of cinemachine are you using ?

Comment: NotImplementedException. I am using the normal 2d cinemachine camera

Comment: Since I was using the 3rd Person Follow camera I was able to do this:
`camera.GetCinemachineComponent<Cinemachine3rdPersonFollow>().CameraDistance = 30;`